# Trying to pick 4 groups of 7 from 28 people based on grade. there are only 7 grades A,B,C,D,E,F,G

Tags: pandas

You can use the below code for creating the df

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Player": ['Sean','Greg','Mike','George','Smith','Brent','Dave','Sandy','Bob','Rob','Anthony','Tony','Todd','Vic','Lima','Bina','Mark','Jerry','Rao','Chris','Nick','Flint','Styne','Dale','Stoli','Popov','Glen','Maxwell'], 
                   "Grade": ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','A','B','C','D','E','F','G']})

print(df)
```

I need 4 teams (groups) from these 28 people. And Should have a random pick of each grade in each of these teams (groups). Such as Team 1 can have any 7 people but all with different grades from A thru G.

I need something similar to below

```
Team     Player     Grade
1        Sandy       A
1        Greg        B
1        Dale        C
1        Anthony     D
1        Rao         E
1        Glen        F
1        Vic         G
2        Sean        A
2        Bina        B
2        Rob         C
2        George      D
2        Popov       E
2        Brent       F
2        Maxwell     G
```

But for 4 teams (groups)

Also try to create it randomly so i can re-run for multiple times with different results.

So far I have tried,

```
df.groupby('Grade').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.choice(range(0, len(x)))])
```

it does give me 1 team back only and than i have to keep reducing the data frame and re-run with remaining people. doesnt seem random to me at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like this with `groupby().transform`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Team'] = df.groupby('Grade').transform(lambda group: np.random.permutation(4))
```

and that results in:

```
     Player Grade  Team
0      Sean     A     1
1      Greg     B     0
2      Mike     C     2
3    George     D     3
4     Smith     E     2
5     Brent     F     1
6      Dave     G     1
7     Sandy     A     0
8       Bob     B     2
9       Rob     C     3
10  Anthony     D     2
11     Tony     E     0
12     Todd     F     0
13      Vic     G     2
14     Lima     A     2
15     Bina     B     3
16     Mark     C     0
17    Jerry     D     1
18      Rao     E     1
19    Chris     F     3
20     Nick     G     3
21    Flint     A     3
22    Styne     B     1
23     Dale     C     1
24    Stoli     D     0
25    Popov     E     3
26     Glen     F     2
27  Maxwell     G     0
```

Here we're using `np.random.permutation` to generate a randomly-ordered array like [3, 0, 1, 2]. We use `lambda` to define a function that returns these, and then use groupby to apply it to each grade-group. Wrappting this in `transform` means the end result will match up with the original df, rather than being a df with just 1 row for each group if we had used `apply`.

To match your desired result format exactly, we can use `range(1, 5)` rather than `4` within the permutation, sort, and change the column order:

```
df['Team'] = df.groupby('Grade').transform(lambda group: np.random.permutation(range(1, 5)))
df = df.sort_values(['Team', 'Grade'])
df = df[['Team', 'Player', 'Grade']]
```

and that gives:

```
    Team   Player Grade
14     1     Lima     A
1      1     Greg     B
16     1     Mark     C
10     1  Anthony     D
18     1      Rao     E
19     1    Chris     F
27     1  Maxwell     G
7      2    Sandy     A
8      2      Bob     B
23     2     Dale     C
3      2   George     D
11     2     Tony     E
12     2     Todd     F
6      2     Dave     G
0      3     Sean     A
22     3    Styne     B
2      3     Mike     C
17     3    Jerry     D
4      3    Smith     E
5      3    Brent     F
13     3      Vic     G
21     4    Flint     A
15     4     Bina     B
9      4      Rob     C
24     4    Stoli     D
25     4    Popov     E
26     4     Glen     F
20     4     Nick     G
```

Comment: Regarding `range(1, 5)`, it's simpler to do `np.random.permutation(4) + 1`, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is get a [random permutation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permutation.html) by each grade.
We can use `transform` to assign team numbers:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
df['Team'] = df.groupby('Grade')['Player'].transform(
    lambda g: rng.permutation(len(g)) + 1
)
```

Example output, pivoted into a more readable table:

```
df.pivot(columns='Grade', index='Team')

      Player
Grade      A      B     C        D      E      F        G
Team                                                     
1      Sandy   Bina  Dale    Jerry  Smith   Glen     Dave
2       Sean  Styne  Mike   George   Tony   Todd      Vic
3       Lima   Greg  Mark    Stoli    Rao  Chris     Nick
4      Flint    Bob   Rob  Anthony  Popov  Brent  Maxwell
```

*<sub>Thanks to [Jacob H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7926383/jacob-h) for the [more idiomatic approach using `transform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77455270/4518341)</sub>*